# How to find two optimal weights in a vector?

Tags: vector

Imagine you're given an unsorted array [5,11,7,4,19,8,11,6,17] and a max weight 23. [similar to Two Sum Problem by a bit different]

One needs to find two optimal weights (by which I mean if two weights that are (almost or not) half of the weight you're trying to find) in this case [5,17], [3,19], [11,11] so I need to return [11,11].

I was taken back by the problem, and could not solve it. [I was not allowed to use structs]

I tried to sort [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 11, 17, 19] and search from both ends and store indexes of values that were <= max weight in a vector as a pair (like v[i], v[i+1] and check them later by their pairs) then return a pair with both largest vals, but got confused.

[although, weights were doubles and I did not see duplicates at that set I did not use unsorted_map(hashMap), might it've worked?]

Can anyone suggest how should I go about this problem? is it similar to "knapsack problem"? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Two Pointer Approach** for the problem.

Algorithm:

1. Sort the array.
2. Have two pointers startIndex and endIndex to 0 and arraySize-1.
3. sum = arr[startIndex] + arr[endIndex]
4. If sum is less than or equal to 23, increment startIndex else decrement endIndex.
5. keep track of closest value using a variable.
6. finish when startIndex == endIndex

**Code in Java**:

```
    public class Solution {


    private ArrayList<Integer> twoSumClosest(ArrayList<Integer> a, int s) {

      // Sort the arraylist
      Collections.sort(a);

      // closests sum we got till now
      int sumClosest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

      // indexes used to traverse
      int startIndex = 0;
      int endIndex = a.size() - 1 ;

      // answer Indexes
      int firstIndex = 1;
      int secondIndex = a.size() - 1;

      while( startIndex < endIndex ) {
        if( a.get(startIndex)  + a.get(endIndex)  > s) {
          endIndex--;
          continue;
        } else {
          if( a.get(startIndex)  + a.get(endIndex)  > sumClosest ) {
            sumClosest = a.get(startIndex)  + a.get(endIndex);
            firstIndex = startIndex;
            secondIndex = endIndex;
          }
          startIndex++;
        }
      }

      ArrayList<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<>();
      ans.add(firstIndex);
      ans.add(secondIndex);
      return ans;
    }

  }
```

**Time Complexity:**  O(nlogn)

O(n) if array was already sorted

**Extra Space Needed:** O(1)

Comment: Thank you, I found your solution really helpful. But it might not work for all cases, so I added another condition to if statement to check if the indexes we chose truly have bigger values compared to our answer.  I added two solution indexes which, at first, assumes first and last values are the solution                                                                               
       ... int temp =v[low]+v[high];
        ...
        else {    if(temp >= sum && (v[low] >= v[idx1] && v[high] <= v[idx2]))  ...}